# Best feature for classifying images based on greenness

Tags: python, matlab, opencv, image-processing, machine-learning

I want to classify several green images based on their "green-ness". 
I have train data where image names are ranked to different classes, say-1,2,3 etc. Now I have given a set of test images to classify based on train data. All images are of green leaves. Class-1 images are more green than that of Class-5 images according to train data. 
Is there any significant way to discern the images based on how green they are?

I tried several ways (all in KNN algorithm) like,

> 1. taking Hue values (HSV color space) of train image and train them in KNN classifier, then applied to test data
> 2. taking green values (RGB color space) and applied the same as above
> 3. taking A values (LAB color space) and applied the same as above

Maximum 58% of accuracy in above procedures I got.

I think, there should be some systematic way to do this. Can anyone give idea from your experience/intuition ?

Thanks!

Comment: provide sample images please. tell us which parts of the images you evaluate
how do you define "green-ness" ?

Comment: As I mentioned, I used Hue value, R value and A value of HSV, RGB and LAB color space respectively to define "green-ness". For the sample image, you can assume any image of green leaves, doesn't matter. All images are "leaves" and they are green and taken by the same camera, in the same time and environment.

Comment: did you apply any masks to get rid of the non-leaf stuff? what about saturation? if somebody would ask me how I define green-ness I'd say that something has to be green and if you have 2 green things the more saturated one would be the "greenest"
without knowing what you do I'd guess that use the wrong features and/or take pixels into consideration that do not represent leaves

Answer (score 0):

Use the green difference as training data

```
greenDifference = (255 + greenChannel - (redChannel + blueChannel)/2)/2;
```

Here is explanation for the above expression http://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/119804-greenness-of-an-rgb-image